# Could not find the right value using the MongoDB aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I need to fetch value as per some user input using MongoDB aggregate function but in my case, I could not return the right value. Here is my code:

```
var cname=req.body.cname;
var id=req.body.id;
Company.collection.aggregate([
        { $match:{$and:[{cname:cname},{_id:{$ne:id}}]}}

])
```

I need to fetch those value by comparing the `cname` value and `_id` is not equals to the given id. But In my case, the user input `id` value is fetching where I need other the user input `id` documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the query as mentioned below:

```
Company.collection.aggregate([
        { $match:{$and:[{cname:cname},{$ne:{_id:id}}]}}

]);
```

See if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

Company.collection.aggregate([
{$match : {$and: [{cname:cname},{$ne:{'_id':ObjectId(id)}}]}}
]);
```